# Converting VBScript's Eqv Operator

Tags: powershell, logical-operators, equivalence

If you google for [PowerShell Eqv](https://www.google.nl/search?q=PowerShell%20Eqv) you currently will find the [VBScript-to-Windows PowerShell Conversion Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee176814.aspx) on top of the list. Yet the answer is much of technical help:

## Eqv Operator

***Definition:*** Performs a logical equivalence on two expressions.
*No doubt Eqv has its uses; we’re just not sure if it has any practical uses. Although there might be a Windows PowerShell equivalent we have to be honest: we didn’t look real hard for one.*

In fact, I used the `Eqv` operator (also written as: `A↔B`) a  number of times in VBScript and likely would have used it in PowerShell if it existed.

## Example

I have a list of groups (`"HR", "SAP", "!IT", "..."`). If a user is a member of all the listed groups and explicitly not a member of groups that are preceded with an escalation mark (like `"!IT"`, which is unraveled to: `$Negate = $True` and `$Group = "IT"`) a specific task should be done. The script needs to iterate through the groups and immediately break the iteration when a group condition is not met (to save time).
A command for this would have been something like:

```
If ($Negate -eqv (IsMember($Group))) {Break}
```

How can I build a logical equivalence operator with a minimum of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take definition quiet literally, you will probably already see a possible way to achieve a logical equivalence operation:

```
If ([Bool]$Expression1 -eq [Bool]$Expression2) {...}
```

But if you take a close look to the truth table you might notice that the results for `Eqv` are exactly the opposite of an `Xor` operation.
Meaning that you can also achieve logical equivalence operation with an inverted `Xor`:

```
If (!(Expression1 -xor $Expression2)) {...}
```

And as it doesn’t matter what you invert for an `Xor` (either the whole operation or one of the expressions), you can even simplify it to:

---

```
If (!Expression1 -xor $Expression2) {...}
```

---

## Check

```
0..3 | ForEach {
    $Expression1, $Expression2 = [Int]($_ / 2), [Int]($_ % 2)
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Expression1 = [Bool]$Expression1
        Expression2 = [Bool]$Expression2
        Equivalence = !$Expression1 -xor $Expression2
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

## Truth Table

```
Expression1 Expression2 Equivalence
----------- ----------- -----------
      False       False        True
      False        True       False
       True       False       False
       True        True        True
```

**Note:** In this solution `$Null` expressions are considered `$False`. This differs from the VBScript `Eqv` implementation but is consistent with other PowerShell operators that contain `$Null` expressions. e.g. The VBScript statement: `If 1 And vbNull Then msgbox "True" Else msgbox "False"`, returns `True` where the PowerShell statement `If (1 -and $Null) {"True"} Else {"False"}`, returns `False`.

## Bitwise

If you looking for a bitwise `Eqv` operator (which should probably be called -`bEqv`, if it existed), then it would be:

```
$Equivalence = -bNot Expression1 -bXOr Expression2    # e.g.: -bNot 3 -bXOr 5 = -7 (-bAnd 0xF = 9)
```

Comment: On the page you linked to in your question there is an "Is this page helpful?" section. If you click on "No", you get an opportunity to let MS know that the documentation is inadequate and say how it could be improved.